# GridView displaying old data

Tags: asp.net-3.5

On the Select event on the Grid View  I went to the next page. After some time if I want to use the same page I got the same data on that page; how could I get out of this problem?

Comment: I've tried to salvage the question, but I recommend (to @harish) that you edit it and clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to what you are asking, but I guess you keep getting the same results no matter what select button you click.

Try to set EnableViewState="False" on grids and see what happens.

Regards,

M.